# What is the use of CLUSTERED AND NON CLUSTERED INDEX on same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I am new to sql and I am wondering if somebody can tell me the use of CLUSTERED AND NON CLUSTERED INDEX on same column. I was looking over some table scripts at my work but didn't understand what is the use of having both clustered and non clustered indexes on one column.its an ID column and it is in all the tables in database.

Comment: Are we correct in assuming you are talking about SQL Server?

Comment: `SQL` is just the **Structured Query Language** - it's no **product** - no database system. What you're referring to is Microsoft's **SQL Server** - a concrete database product.

Comment: If you'd like to learn more about indexes, have a look into my [SQL Index Tutorial (also for SQL Server)](http://use-the-index-luke.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In really simple terms the difference between a CLUSTERED and NON CLUSTERED INDEX is that the CLUSTERED index is a physical ordering of the records in the table, based on the values in the indexed field, whereas a NON CLUSTERED index is a logical ordering of the records in the table based on values in the indexed field(s). This logical ordering is decided by the SQL database engine based on the statistical distribution of values in the table.

Another important difference is that for a table you can have only one CLUSTERED index (because it's a physical ordering of data stored in that table). While you can have many different NON CLUSTERED indexes on different fields, on the same table.

With that being said, of course you can have both CLUSTERED and NON CLUSTERED indexes on the same field of a table and that's useful because generally CLUSTERED indexes are specifically good at accessing data sequentially while NON CLUSTERED indexes can be optimized for random access to the data by the SQL database engine. This way a combination of CLUSTERED and NON CLUSTERED indexes on the same column gives you highly optimized access to records in that table when searching based on values in the indexed field.

Comment: This doesn't explain why you would have an NCI and a CI on the same column. The non leaf level pages of the 2 indexes would be almost the same so there would be no particular benefit for random access when looking up by specific id (especially given that the NCI uses the CI key as a row locator anyway so the CI will **still** have to be traversed!). Also neither of them are guaranteed to be in physical order (fragmentation). They are both only in logical order with next and previous pages being denoted by fields in the page header.

Comment: @Martin There is little difference when looking up a single row by a single ID in the NCI/CI cases. In this case, if the ID column is in all the tables in the database, it could be wrong or it could be right, it's hard to know if these IDs are even representing the same thing. It sounds like a code smell, but there are also legitimate reasons. What if the OP overlooked that the NCI had included columns (and it became covering for a particular query)? Then an NCI scan would probable be preferred to a table scan on this table.

Comment: @Cade - Yep, that's true. I noticed an error in my original comment. The non leaf pages of course wouldn't be almost the same as the CI would probably have a lot more pages so the tree would be wider and deeper but still any lookups from the NCI would just have to traverse the CI anyway.

Answer (score 4):

A clustered index is not really an index - in the sense that it's all the data organized in the tree according to the key.

A non-clustered index is just the key in the tree with any additional included columns and the necessary bookmark to get to the data row when necessary.  The data itself may be stored in a clustered index or a heap.  And there can be many non-clustered indexes, but obviously only one real way to choose to store the data.

For performance of a particular query, a covering non-clustered index on a heap (or whatever, it doesn't matter, since the index is covering) can often easily outperform a clustered index, since the index may fit more rows per page and requires no bookmark lookups to get data out of the row, while a clustered index seek/scan is going to read and discard a lot more data and fit less rows per page.

Typically you will want a clustered index and the clustering key should be narrow, static, increasing, unique.

But for query performance you really want to look at non-clustered indexes and have a selection which are covering and which have sort orders in the right direction where applicable.

Comment: You still haven't given any use cases as to why you would have an NCI and a CI on a single `id` column. I can imagine a narrow index on `id` might be useful for certain kinds of queries such as semi joins, or enforcing foreign key constraints - can't really think of any other use cases?

Comment: @Martin An NCI with a single id and no included columns will still be faster for existence verification then a CI on the id because you will fit more data per page (assuming the table is relatively wide). But, you're right, this scenario would only be useful for a case where the id is a foreign key, for instance an FK to another table for rows which match a certain criteria.  In general, an NCI which is covering is going to be preferred. In that case the bookmark and choice of CI is irrelevant, because the index is covering. You should have a CI, certainly, but don't rely on it for read perf.